# Python position of a character in a string in a list

Tags: python, list, loops

So, say I have a list with 5 strings. The strings are seven characters long.

```
list = ["000000A", "000001A", "000002B", "000003C", "000004C"]
```

Now, with this list, I want to find what position the string is in the list which the 7th character is equal to A. Then I want to find what position the string is in the list which the 7th character is equal to B. Then finally the same for C.

I was thinking along the lines of:

```
letters = ["A","B","C"]
for i in range(len(letters)):
   for j in range(len(list)):
           for k, l in enumerate(list[j][6]):
               if l == (letters[i]):
                   print(k)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction or explain why this would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = ["000000A", "000001A", "000002B", "000003C", "000004C"]
a = ([i for i,s in enumerate(lst) if s[6] == "A"])
```

So to get all three:

```
a = []
b = []
c= []
for i, s in enumerate(lst):
    if s[6] == "A":
        a.append(i)
    elif s[6] == "B":
        b.append(i)
    elif s[6] == "C":
        c.append(i)
```

Or you can store all in a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) using s[6] as the key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

inds = defaultdict(list)
for i, s in enumerate(lst):
    inds[s[6]].append(i)

print(inds)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'A': [0, 1], 'C': [3, 4], 'B': [2]})
```

Comment: @TonySmears, no worries. I did not know if you just wanted to print or store but the logic is the same, you could also use a defaultdict using the s[6] char as the key and appending the indexes

Comment: yea I did thank you very much. With the basic code I managed to implement it. Thanks again :)